# Relating Binding in RecyclerView

Tags: android, xamarin, android-recyclerview

```
<Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Support.RecyclerView.MvxRecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            local:MvxBind="ItemsSource productlist" 
            local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/listofproduct"/>.
```

and

```
mRecyclerView = FindViewById<RecyclerView> (Resource.Id.recyclerview);
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager (this,LinearLayoutManager.Horizontal,false);
mRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager (mLayoutManager);
```

I am getting this error:

> Caused by: md52ce486a14f4bcd95899665e9d932190b.JavaProxyThrowable:
>   Cirrious.CrossCore.Exceptions.MvxException: Error finding resource ids
>   for MvxBinding - please make sure ResourcesToCopy are linked into the
>   executable ---> System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source
>   type to destination type.

Comment: Instead of Resource.Id.recyclerview use this mRecyclerView =(Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Support.RecyclerView.MvxRecyclerView) findViewById (R.id.recyclerview); and in findViewById the f is small letter

Answer (score 1):

I think the exception is raised as you are trying to cast

```
Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Support.RecyclerView.MvxRecyclerView
```

to `RecyclerView` by your code above

```
mRecyclerView = FindViewById<RecyclerView> (Resource.Id.recyclerview);
```

This might help

```
mRecyclerView = FindViewById<MvxRecyclerView> (Resource.Id.recyclerview);
```

Comment: I think you are on the right way, but you should not cast views in FindViewById. Rather use `mRecyclerView = FindViewById<MvxRecyclerView> (Resource.Id.recyclerview);`